# Enabling logwriter in Userfrosting

Tags: slim, userfrosting

I'm trying to use the built-in Slim logwriter, but not successful so far.

This is what I'm trying, but I get an error.

1. Change to config_userfrosting.php:

   ```
   /*Create a log writer */

   $logWriter = new \UserFrosting\LogWriter(fopen('C:\xampp\htdocs\userfrosting\log\dev_logfile.log', 'a'));

   $app->configureMode('dev', function () use ($app, $public_path, $uri_public_root) {
   $app->config([
       'log.enable' => true,
       'log.writer' => $logWriter,
       'debug' => false,
   ```
2. Call Log writer from index.php:

$app->log->debug("This is a test from the logger...");

Error received:

```
  PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: logWriter in \\userfrosting\\config-userfrosting.php on line 33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a variable to be accessed inside your closure (`configureMode`), you need to pass it in with the list of `use(...)` arguments:

```
$app->configureMode('dev', function () use ($app, $public_path, $uri_public_root, $logWriter) {

    $app->config([
        'log.enable' => true,
        'log.writer' => $logWriter,
        'debug' => false,
        ...
});
```

Comment: I updated the use(..) arguments as shown. However, now getting the following error:   `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'UserFrosting\\LogWriter' not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\userfrosting\\config-userfrosting.php`

Comment: Got it. I needed to use \Slim\Logwriter instead. Thanks @alexw.